# Django sendmail SSL error EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, django, email, ssl

I have this nasty error that i can't wrap my head around. Have been trying to solve it for quite a while now. Any help would be highly appriciated. I'll paste the stacktrace, I also made some debugging with Wireshark and i'll post that as well.

I have tried to upgrade python packages that could be related to the ssl communication without any success. This problem only happens when EMAIL_USE_TLS is True and it will happen for both debug mode and production. I first thought that maybe the SMTP server is using on old version of ssl but that was not the case. As the Wireshark capture will tell the ssl seems to be established, then in the next request the server will close unexpectedly.

The settings i use is:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp_server'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I do nothing strange when sending the mail, here is the code:

```
def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
    return send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

The error stacktrace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 477, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 474, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 52, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Documents\GitHub\django-dropin\api\views.py", line 18, in register
    user = serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Documents\GitHub\django-dropin\api\serializers.py", line 86, in create
    is_sent = user.send_confirmation_email(confirmation_instance=confirmation_instance)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Documents\GitHub\django-dropin\users\models.py", line 139, in send_confirmation_email
    is_sent = self.email_user(subject, message, from_email)  # Returns the number of delivered emails
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Documents\GitHub\django-dropin\users\models.py", line 132, in email_user
    return send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 342, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\Metadeath\Envs\dropin\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 64, in open
    self.connection.starttls(keyfile=self.ssl_keyfile, certfile=self.ssl_certfile)
  File "c:\users\metadeath\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\smtplib.py", line 770, in starttls
    server_hostname=self._host)
  File "c:\users\metadeath\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "c:\users\metadeath\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "c:\users\metadeath\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "c:\users\metadeath\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:749)
```

[Wireshark capture for client and smtp server when establishing ssl connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCfAg.png)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It was something wrong with the certificate, the company that host the SMTP server they the problem do occur for some Python and some PHP modules. I suspect it have to be something with the openSSL version I have (OpenSSL 1.0.2j). Now it's solved anyway so this thread may be closed.

In case anyone else come by this problem, contact your SMTP host company and they may provide you with a different relay.

Good luck to all developers out there!